# Why is Firestore's ignoreUndefinedProperties option false by default?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are using Firestore in the product we are developing, and we occasionally get errors caused by trying to add undefined values to a document.

As a general rule, I believe that external technologies should be operated according to the designer’s philosophy, and I thought that options such as ignoreUndefinedProperties should be applied with default settings unless there is a reason to do otherwise.

However, I am considering setting ignoreUndefinedProperties to true because we sometimes accidentally try to update data with value undefined.

Why does ignoreUndefinedProperties have a default value of false?
And, What do you think are the dangers or disadvantages of setting this to true?